# Load balancing between WebSphere and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, server, load-balancing

We are moving on to JWS (Tomcat Server) from IBM Websphere server , in this exercise we are bringing the websphere down and add tomcat server . So right now in cluster we have Tomcat and Websphere server . What we are seeing is more traffic is going to Webpshere than Tomcat . Also we have an Load Balancer(LB) infront of these servers . Any one have any thoughts ?

Why the request always going to websphere then Tomcat .

Comment: This might depend on your load balancer configuration. If your requests could be processed fast and load balancer sends request to first available server (and you configured websphere as first server) then websphere will get more requests

Comment: You say more traffic and then you say always goes to websphere - if it’s the former then that’s just normal load balancing, it doesn’t just work 50/50. If the latter, you have set it up incorrectly.

Comment: We have 5 IBM servers started in port 9445 , as part of migration stopped one of the websphere server and started JWS server in port 9445 . We do not see much traffic in JWS server . is it due to the response time from the JWS is bad compared to IBM server . We changed many parameters in JWS start-up property eg- maxActiveThread , MaxKeepAliveRequests . Not sure these params help LB to send more threads to JWS side

Comment: If you need equally distributed traffic for all 5 servers you need to configure load balancer to route requests using round robin algorithm. And even after that if you use sticky sessions amount of traffic could be different for servers